# How to retrieve Facebook comments for my custom page that has facebook comment plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my page: http://gimplearn.net/watermark.php/1-beetle-gif?id=11175
I have 2 comments in the fb comment plugin

I tried looking around and I found that in order to get object id for my page I can use

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://gimplearn.net/watermark.php/1-beetle-gif?id=11175

to retrieve facebook object id for my page (which as a fb comment plugin)

Then I found this

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?access_token=78611337341|Ixb0Cbsny2sOg4wdaBCJJA1B5ks&ids=1693425987438115

The access token is my comment app's access token.

Why is it not giving me my page's fb comments?

What is the link/api that I can use in order to retrieve the fb comments that is on that page?

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a way for google bot to see facebook comments as it wasn't able to see fb comments on my page. So I thought of printing out raw text comments.
But I found a better work-around and posted detailed description in link below:

http://gimplearn.net/viewtopic.php/Does-googlebot-see-my-facebook-comments-Now-it-does-?f=5&t=1443